# Node run command that prompts the user

Tags: node.js, command-line, child-process

I'm trying to run a command (aws configure) from a .js file called with node. I've been using [child_process](https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html) which allows me to execute a command or batch file. However when that file would normally prompt the user for something like a username and password, I am unable to have that interaction take place.

I tried using [process.stdin](https://docs.nodejitsu.com/articles/command-line/how-to-prompt-for-command-line-input/) with node in order to perhaps use node as the middle man of a user's input, but I am unable to link the two together.

If anyone has any ideas that would be great!

```
var spawn = require('child_process').spawn;
var mystdin = process.stdin;
var conf = spawn('aws configure', {input: mystdin, shell: true});

//When command returns
conf.stdout.on('data', function(data) {
    console.log('stdout: ' + data);

    //prompt for input
    mystdin.resume();
    mystdin.setEncoding('utf8');
    var util = require('util');

    mystdin.on('data', function (text) {
        //INSERT ANSWER HERE
        console.log('received data:', util.inspect(text));
        if (text === 'quit\n') {
            done();
        }
    });

    function done() {
        console.log('Now that process.stdin is paused, there is nothing more to do.');
        process.exit();
    }
});

conf.stderr.on('data', function(data) {
    console.log('stdout: ' + data);
});

conf.on('close', function(code) {
   console.log('child precess exited with code ' + code);
});
```

This is just the path I was currently going down. If anyone has a better suggestion let me know!

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Two ideas: first, I think the arguments are supposed to be in the second parameters.  Second, maybe the aws command doesn't realize it is an interactive terminal or something. You may try with child_process like that, or if that doesn't work, with `pty.js`:

```
var pty = require('pty.js');

var term = pty.spawn('aws', ['configure'], {
  name: 'xterm-color',
  cols: 80,
  rows: 30,
  cwd: process.env.HOME,
  env: process.env
});

term.on('data', function(data) {
  console.log(data);
});
```